# How to integrate Here Maps Api to Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, maps, integration, here-api

I'm setting up a new server, and want to use Here APIs. Is a way of doing it?

The server is developed using Spring boot and I'm using Here APIs for maps, geocoding and autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no different way for spring boot. You can simply call the API using RestTemplate like shown below. Hope this helps!

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        //you can replace this with any Here API you need
        final String uri = "https://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json"
                + "?app_id=xxxx"
                + "&app_code=xxxx"
                + "&beginHighlight=%3Cb%3E"
                + "&endHighlight=%3C/b%3E"
                + "&maxresults=20"
                + "&query=India&gen=9";

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! You saved me there!